# Need help killing the splash event so app doesnt exit to it

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have created a splash event and have it set to sleep for 3secs. Everything works fine but when you go to exit the application it takes you back to the splash. Is there a way to kill this with the code that I have or do I need to write this in a different manner.

```
public class splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer =  new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openApp = new Intent("com.iqmobile.chris.IQMOBILEACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openApp);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splash.this.finish();` after you start `startActivity(openApp);`

```
  Intent openApp = new Intent("com.iqmobile.chris.IQMOBILEACTIVITY");
  startActivity(openApp);

  splash.this.finish();
```

**Second Solution**

in AndroidManifest file

```
<activity android:noHistory="true"
            android:name=".splash" />
```

Comment: Wow..So simple and I missed it. Thanks Samir!

Answer (score 0):

add  finsh(); in code as :

```
Intent openApp = new Intent("com.iqmobile.chris.IQMOBILEACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openApp);
               splash.this.finsh();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSplashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(3000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(FirstActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    mSplashThread.start();
}
```